# how can i remove validation for progress bar for save functionality

Tags: jquery, validation, progress-bar

I have Progress bar with two buttons 'Submit' and 'Save'.

When i click on the Save button,its validating the fields,How can i customise that only for submit functionality i need validation .But for save functionality i dont need the validation.This is my code

```
$(".next").click(function () {
            $('#msform').validate();
            if (!$('#msform').valid()) {
                return false;
            }

            
            current_fs = $(this).parent();
            next_fs = $(this).parent().next(); 

            
            //Add Class Active
            $("#progressbar div").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

            
            //show the next fieldset
            next_fs.show();
            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
                step: function (now) {
                    // for making fielset appear animation
                    opacity = 1 - now;

                    current_fs.css({
                        'display': 'none',
                        'position': 'relative'
                    });
                    next_fs.css({ 'opacity': opacity });
                },
                duration: 600
            });
        });

        $(".previous").click(function () {

            current_fs = $(this).parent();
            previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

            //Remove class active
            $("#progressbar div").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

            //show the previous fieldset
            previous_fs.show();

            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
                step: function (now) {
                    // for making fielset appear animation
                    opacity = 1 - now;

                    current_fs.css({
                        'display': 'none',
                        'position': 'relative'
                    });
                    previous_fs.css({ 'opacity': opacity });
                },
                duration: 600
            });
        });



        //$(".submit").click(function () {
        //    return false;
        //})
```

How can i differentiate the save and submit click for validation.Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use formnovalidate attribute in the save button.

Answer (score 0):

Use formnovalidate="formnovalidate" in save button